# How to resolve TinyButStrong's 'at least one tag corresponding to w:tr is not found' error?

Tags: libreoffice, mailmerge, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I'm creating a project to mail merge a given .odt file and provide a .odt output. When i'm performing the mail merge operation it provides me this error

`TinyButStrong Error in block's definition [CiviCRM.display_name...]: at least one tag corresponding to w:tr is not found. Check opening tags, closing tags and embedding levels.`

**Myfilecontent.odt**

```
[CRM. display_name;block=w:tr]

Date: 2/3/2020

Dear [CRM.postal_greeting;block=w:tr],

Thank you for joining the event...
```

I have no idea how to resolve this. could someone help me to solve it? 
Thanks in advance!

**Update**

After i replaced w:tr with tbs:row, still I'm receiving a similar error

> TinyButStrong Error in block's definition [CRM.display_name...]: at
>   least one tag corresponding to tbs:row is not found. Check opening
>   tags, closing tags and embedding levels.

Answer (score 0):

`w:tr` is an XML entity for Ms Word , not ODT.

You should use the alias `block=tbs:row` so that its is format independent.

Comment: Thank you! but when i replace `block=tbs:row` instead of  `w:tr` still I'm receiving this error ,please check the updated question. please help me to solve this

Comment: do this occur due to a version problem?

Comment: i cleared the format in the text and tried it but still occurring this. please help me

Comment: Are the TBS fields placed inside a row of a table ?

Comment: you mean in the template ?

Comment: The fields having parameter `block` with the realtive syntax (such as `block=tbs:row`) must be inside the block. In your case it means that all fields with parameter `block=tbs:row` must be inside a row of a table. Is that so ?

Comment: One possible cause of the message could be that your snippet `block=w:tr` contains a special character (like space) that would be not visible in the HTML error message. Can you check at the source of the HTML message to see if the code that bound `tbs:row` contains no space or other ?

Comment: ' if ($this->f_Loc_EnlargeToTag($Txt,$Loc,$Block,false)===false) return $this->meth_Misc_Alert($Loc,'at least one tag corresponding to '.$Loc->PrmLst['block'].' is not found. Check opening tags, closing tags and embedding levels.',false,'in block\'s definition'); ' this is the statement and there is no extra space. do this occur due to a problem in the uploaded file syntax?

Comment: I don’t think so. Could you send to me your template or a snippet that reproduces the problem ? So I could investigate deeper ?

Comment: can i know any other way to contact you, even email address. so i can provide all the relevant information

Comment: https://wetransfer.com or  /https://www.tinybutstrong.com/support.php#contact